given a point and a circle, find the point(s) on that circle which would have a tangent that intersects the point
I'm trying to find the points on a circle of radius $o_{r}$ that have a tangent line which intersects the point $P_{s}$
BACKGROUND:
This is my first post, if i messed something up let me know!
I'm trying to make an obstacle avoidance algorithm for a robot, going from $P_{s}$ to $P_{e}$. if the path intersects the circle $P_{o}$, then i "bend out" the line so that it scrapes the danger zone. if i can find where a tangent would intersect $P_{s}$ (and $P_{e}$) then i can have the robot follow those tangents safely. Ive omitted the end point equations because its practically copy-paste of the start point equations.
DESCRIPTION:
given a point $P_{s}$, and a circle $c$, find the point(s) on that circle which would have a tangent that intersects $P_{s}$
GIVEN:
$P_{s}=\left(6.7,3.37\right)$ Goal Intersect
$P_{o}=\left(1.56,2.45\right)$ Circle Center
$o_{r}=2.3$ Circle Radius
I need a solution that works with (almost) any numbers in the above values
$m_{ts}=-\frac{\left(P_{s}.x-P_{o}.x\right)}{\left(P_{s}.y-P_{o}.y\right)}$
$P_{ts}=\left(\frac{o_{r}^{2}\left(P_{s}.x-P_{o}.x\right)}{\left(\left(P_{s}.x-P_{o}.x\right)^{2}+\left(P_{s}.y-P_{o}.y\right)^{2}\right)},\frac{o_{r}^{2}\left(P_{s}.y-P_{o}.y\right)}{\left(\left(P_{s}.x-P_{o}.x\right)^{2}+\left(P_{s}.y-P_{o}.y\right)^{2}\right)}\right)+P_{o}$
this gets me a line, and where the line intersects the circle is where the point(s) of tangency are.
$l:0=m_{ts}\left(x-P_{ts}.x\right)-y+P_{ts}.y$ point-slope form of line
$c:0=\left(x-P_{o}.x\right)^{2}+\left(y-P_{o}.y\right)^{2}-o_{r}^{2}$ equation for the circle
this is as far as ive gotten. i've got no idea where to go from here. setting $l = c$ didnt work, and neither did substitution.
if you want, heres a link to the desmos project im working in. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sthhjugipy

Setting the right-hand sides of equations $l$ and $c$ gives you another curve, but substituting $y=m_{ts}\left(x-P_{ts}.x\right)+P_{ts}.y$ into the equation $c$ results in a quadratic equation in which $x$ is the only unknown. So that should work, although I would still favor something more like a vector construction.

Using your notation, the parametric equation for your circle is
$$\mathbf r_c(\varphi)=\mathbf P_0+o_r(\cos \varphi,\sin \varphi),\enspace \varphi\in[0,2\pi]$$
Therefore, the tangent line at some $\varphi=\varphi_0$ would be
$$\mathbf r_t(t)=\mathbf r_c(\varphi_0)+\mathbf r_c'(\varphi_0)\,t,\enspace t\in\mathbf R$$
Now we impose $\mathbf r_t(t^\ast)=\mathbf P_s$ and set up a system of equations for both coordinates:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x_s=x_0+o_r\cos\varphi_0-o_r\sin\varphi_0\,t^\ast\\
&y_s=y_0+o_r\sin\varphi_0+o_r\cos\varphi_0\,t^\ast
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Isolating the $t^\ast$ in each equation and equating them we get to solve this other equation in $\varphi_0$:
$$\begin{aligned}
-\dfrac{1}{\sin\varphi_0}\left(\dfrac{x_s-x_0}{o_r}-\cos\varphi_0\right)&=\dfrac{1}{\cos\varphi_0}\left(\dfrac{y_s-y_0}{o_r}-\sin\varphi_0\right)\\
\dfrac{x_s-x_0}{o_r}\cos\varphi_0+\dfrac{y_s-y_0}{o_r}\sin\varphi_0&=1\\
\pm\dfrac{1}{o_r}\sqrt{(x_s-x_0)^2+(y_s-y_0)^2}\cos\left[\varphi_0-\arctan\left(\dfrac{y_s-y_0}{x_s-x_0}\right)\right]&=1\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{\varphi_0=\arctan\left(\dfrac{y_s-y_0}{x_s-x_0}\right)\pm\arccos\left(\dfrac{o_r}{\sqrt{(x_s-x_0)^2+(y_s-y_0)^2}}\right)}}}$$
Substituting the values we get $\varphi_0\simeq(0.753,\, 5.53)$ which is the equivalent to $t^\ast\simeq(-0.992,\,0.882)$ respectively. The points you are asking about are approximately $(7.12,5.69)$ and $(7.02,2.17)$ respectively too.
